# Using big M values for a constraint

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, constraint, combinatorial-optimization, big-m

I want to enforce $x_{i,j}=x_{k,j}\implies z_i \neq z_k$ where $k = i-1$ so I used \begin{align}z_k + 1 - (x_{i,j} - x_{k,j})) \leq z_i \leq z_k - 1 - (x_{i,j} - x_{k,j})\quad\text{for each $j$}\end{align} as $x$ is an integer variable where $x \in \{{0,1}\}$ and $z$ is an integer.

I tried this on an example but I kept getting errors for the $z$ values
\begin{align} 
x_{1,1} = 0,  &&x_{1,2} = 1,\\
x_{2,1} = 0, &&x_{2,2} = 1, \\
x_{3,1} = 1, &&x_{3,2} = 0, \\
x_{4,1} = 1, &&x_{4,2} = 0, \\
\text{and }&&1 \leq z\leq 2
\end{align}
so 
\begin{align}
z_1 + 1 - (x_{2,1} - x_{1,1})) &\leq z_2 \leq z_1 - 1 - (x_{2,1} - x_{1,1})\\
z_1 + 1 - (x_{2,2} - x_{1,2})) &\leq z_2 \leq z_1 - 1 - (x_{2,2} - x_{1,2})\\
z_2 + 1 - (x_{3,1} - x_{2,1})) &\leq z_3 \leq z_2 - 1 - (x_{3,1} - x_{2,1})\\
z_2 + 1 - (x_{3,2} - x_{2,2})) &\leq z_3 \leq z_2 - 1 - (x_{3,2} - x_{2,2})\\
z_3 + 1 - (x_{4,1} - x_{3,1})) &\leq z_4 \leq z_3 - 1 - (x_{4,1} - x_{3,1})\\
z_3 + 1 - (x_{4,2} - x_{3,2})) &\leq z_4 \leq z_3 - 1 - (x_{4,2} - x_{3,2}).
\end{align}

What is the error?

Comment: Your formulation instead enforces $$x_{i,j}=x_{k,j}\implies z_k<z_i<z_k.$$ In other words, you have an AND where you want an OR.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I got it Dr, .. I really need if $z_i \neq z_k$ then $z_i > z_k$  OR (not AND) $z_i < z_k$ .. I will think of it again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Introduce three binary variables $y_{i,k,s}$, where $s\in\{1,2,3\}$, to indicate whether $z_i < z_k$, $z_i = z_k$, or $z_i > z_k$, respectively. The constraints are then:
\begin{align}
\sum_s y_{i,k,s} &= 1 \tag1 \\
z_i + 1 - z_k &\le M_1(1-y_{i,k,1}) \tag2 \\
-(1-y_{i,k,2}) \le x_{i,j} + x_{k,j} - 1 &\le 1-y_{i,k,2} \tag3\\
z_k + 1 - z_i &\le M_3(1-y_{i,k,3}) \tag4 
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ selects one of the three cases.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces $y_{i,k,1} = 1 \implies z_i < z_k$.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $y_{i,k,2} = 1 \implies x_{i,j} + x_{k,j} = 1$, which is the same as $x_{i,j} \ne x_{k,j}$ because $x$ is binary.  This is the contrapositive of your desired implication.
Constraint $(4)$ enforces $y_{i,k,3} = 1 \implies z_i > z_k$.

Comment: thank you for your continuous and extreme support .. I have used another approach and posted it .. please tell me if it is right or the error in it https://or.stackexchange.com/a/4116/3480

Answer (score 4):

in CPLEX with all APIs you can use logical constraints that will help you to model that:

```
dvar int x;
dvar int y;
dvar int z;
dvar int t;

subject to
{
  (x==y) => (z!=t);
}
```

in [OPL](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/) for instance. But you can write the same with C++, java, python ...

Comment: I use Gurobi with Matlab .. so you can imagine !

Comment: With CPLEX you can use logical constraints with Matlab as can be seen in the example foodmanu.m

Comment: The problem in Gurobi with Matlab we write the whole model as one matrix, not even like Gurobi with any other platforms

Answer (score 1):

Thank to Dr @RobPratt 
I think the answer will be to introduce a binary variable $w_{i,j}$ to indicate whether $z_i=j$. in other words to enforce
$x_{i,j} = x_{k,j} \implies w_{i,j} + w_{k,j} = 1 $ while 
\begin{align} 
\sum_j w_{i,j} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$}\\
\sum_j j w_{i,j} &= z_i &&\text{for all $i$}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Your first constraint uses $i$ in two different ways.  Also, there is no connection with $x$ and the other variables.  Do you have bounds on $z$?

Comment: @RobPratt sorry it was a mistake I modified it .. I mean $\sum_j$ not $\sum_i$ .. and z is integer from $0$ to $z_n$

Comment: another mistake and it was $\sum_j w_{i,j}$

Comment: OK, now you need to link $x$ and $w$.

Comment: yes I will enforce $x_{i,j}=x_{k,j} \implies w_{i,j}+w_{k,j}=1$  as you taught me yesterday

Comment: I think you want $w_{i,t}+w_{k,t} \le 1$ instead because $j$ plays two different roles here.

Comment: @RobPratt .. yes exactly .. I thought of $-1(2 - x_{i,j} - x_{k,j}) \leq w_{i,t} + w_{k,t} - 1 \leq 1(2 - x_{i,j} - x_{k,j})$ based on $x_{i,j} = x_{k,j} = 1 \implies w_{i,t} + w_{k,t} = 1$ but now I don't know what it needs to be $w_{i,j} + w_{k,j} \leq 1$ as it is indeed $\leq 1$ not $=1$

Comment: Rewriting in conjunctive normal form leads to \begin{align}w_{i,t}+w_{k,t}&\le 3-(x_{i,j}+x_{k,j})\\w_{i,t}+w_{k,t}&\le 1+(x_{i,j}+x_{k,j})\end{align}

Comment: @RobPratt I think only the first one: $w_{i,t} + w_{k,t} \leq 3 - (x_{i,j}+x_{k,j})$ is sufficient and the other is redundant w.r.t to the one after adding another constraint $\sum_i w_{i,j} = \text{a constant } \text{for each j}$ , am I right?

Comment: The second one is needed when $x_{i,j}=x_{k,j}=0$.